# Heap corruption in OpenCV program

Tags: opencv, mat, heap-corruption

I have created a variable hisTotF like

```
cv::Mat hisTotF=cv::Mat(1,60,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0));
```

I am trying to initialize the elements  to zero. When I compile this program runs fine but when I run it then while initializing the 6th element in the array it gives a "Heap exception". I am trying to initialize the elements  to zero by the command `histTotF.at<double>(1,6)=0`.

Am I running out of memory. The program excited with the code `0xC0000374`. I am running OpenCV in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1):

```
histTotF.at<double>(1,6) = 0;
```

This mean the pixel at the **second** row and the seventh column. You have only one row so you should use:

```
histTotF.at<double>(0,6) = 0;
```

in order to edit the pixel at the **first** row and the seventh column. Indecies are zero-based in `cv::Mat`.

---

Anyway, constructing `cv::Mat` using:

```
cv::Mat hisTotF=cv::Mat(1,60,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0));
```

is enough to make it all zeros.

If you want to go through all of the pixels in one row and change their values in fast way way, you may use `cv::Mat::ptr` :

```
auto row_ptr = hisToF.ptr<double>(0); //Pointer to the first row.
for(size_t col_idx=0; col_idx<hisToF.cols; ++hisToF.cols){
    row_ptr[col_idx]= 0; // Or whatever value you want
}
```

Comment: @fja: You are welcome and Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find an answer useful and cover all your question, you may accept it using the green tick in left of the question. You can also Up/Down vote it according to your impression about it.